# how not to loop twice on the same items - RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

I have this loop :

```
<div>
<% @ingredientsOfRecipes.each do |item| %>
  <ul>
    <%= item["name"] %>
    <%@fridge.each do |f|%>
    <% item['ingredients'].each do |ingredient| %>
      <li style="display: flex; flex-drirection: row; align-items: center">

        <% if ingredient.include? f.content%>
          <p style="color: green">
            
            <%=ingredient%>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-check" style="color: green; margin-left: 10px"></i>
          </p>
          
        <% elsif ingredient.exclude? f.content%>
          <p style="color: red">
            <%=ingredient%>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" style="color: red; margin-left: 10px"></i>
          </p>
        <%end%>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    <%end%>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

On the @fridge variables, I have 4 values.
and once I loop on a particular ingredient, I don't want to loop on it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that are not clear for me in your code, but right now I can't do questions, so I hope you can correct me if something is not working. Why you have `elseif` instead of only `else`?

If you want to stop the loop, simple use the `break` word wherever you need:

```
<% @ingredientsOfRecipes.each do |item| %>
  <ul>
    <%= item["name"] %>
    <% @fridge.each do |f|%>
    <% item['ingredients'].each do |ingredient| %>
      <li style="display: flex; flex-drirection: row; align-items: center">
        <% break if ingredient.include? 'my_ingredient_that_should break_the_loop'%>

        <% if ingredient.include? f.content %>
          <p style="color: green">
            
            <%=ingredient%>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-check" style="color: green; margin-left: 10px"></i>
          </p>
          
        <% elsif ingredient.exclude? f.content%>
          <p style="color: red">
            <%=ingredient%>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" style="color: red; margin-left: 10px"></i>
          </p>
        <%end%>
      </li>
    <% end %>
    <%end%>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

And trying to do your code more clear: supposing @fridge is a collection of objects and item['ingredients'] is an array of strings (so ingredient is a String) you can try something like this:

```
<% @ingredientsOfRecipes.each do |item| %>
  <ul>
    <%= item["name"] %>
    <% item['ingredients'].each do |ingredient| %>
      <li style="display: flex; flex-drirection: row; align-items: center">
        <% break if ingredient.include? 'my_ingredient_that_should break_the_loop'%>

        <% if @fridge.collect(&:content).any? {|c| ingredient.include? c } %>
          <p style="color: green">
            <%= ingredient %>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-check" style="color: green; margin-left: 10px"></i>
          </p>
        <% else %>
          <p style="color: red">
            <%= ingredient %>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" style="color: red; margin-left: 10px"></i>
          </p>
        <%end%>
      </li>
    <%end%>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Is that your question?